# Cycles Render reduces workspace by strange cube

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, mesh, objects

When I render an image it gets cropped by some kind of cube, making all objects outside invisible. The top view is what I want, the bottom what I get
[image]

Do you have any ideas about the reason or the solution?
There is no such cube in my project.

EDIT: Moving everything around (by pressing A and G) changes position of project inside this "room", but does not solve the problem due to animations that would need to be moved separately keyframe by keyframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is some hidden object in your scene that is not visible in the viewport but still appears in your render.
With the mouse cursor over the 3D view, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to unhide all objects in the current scene

Comment: That was it, I thought they are not included in render

Comment: Blender uses separate settings for visibility and renderability, it is generally very useful, but can sometimes have these strange side effects.